# Solve the inequality $|x^2-2|<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, absolute-value

I'm trying to solve inequalities that include absolute values. The way we solved these questions in class is different than what I am used to. The teacher would take the positive and negative possibilities of the inequality and treat them separately. I am trying to solve this as a union of intervals.

$$|x^2-2|<1$$

Normally I would just write this as:
$$-\sqrt{3} < x < -1 \text{ and } 1 < x < \sqrt{3}$$

However this is not correct I don't believe.

Comment: That looks correct to me. when you break it out, you will have 1<x^2<3 , then -3<x<3 and x<-1 and x>1. When you combine, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Hints:

$$|x^2-2|<1\iff -1<x^2-2<1\iff 1<x^2<3\ldots$$

Answer (score 3):

$$|x^2-2|<1\iff-1< x^2-2 <1$$
$$-1< x^2-2 <1\iff1<x^2<3$$
$$1<x^2<3\iff x^2-1>0\space \&\space x^2-3<0$$
$$x^2-1>0\space \&\space x^2-3<0 \iff x\in((-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty))\cap(-\sqrt 3,\sqrt 3)$$
$$ x\in((-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty))\cap(-\sqrt 3,\sqrt 3)\iff x\in(-\sqrt3,-1)\cup(1,\sqrt3)$$

Comment: Change the intersection symbol in your last line to a union one, or else that denotes the empty set...

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain the step when you get the inequality of: x^2-1>0

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ +1

Comment: This is correct, but is possibly the most confusing answer possible, and thus not really “helpful” in this context. In particular, why do you keep repeating yourself?

Answer (score 1):

$|x^2-2|<1$

$-1<x^2-2<1$

$1<x^2$ or $x^2<3$

$1<x$, $-1>x$, or $-\sqrt{3}<x<\sqrt{3}$

Therefore, 
$-\sqrt{3}<x<-1$ and $1<x<\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Your last line's missing a minus sign to the left of the leftmost $\;\sqrt3\;$

Comment: Instead of an 'or' in the third line, you should have an 'and'.

Comment: What does “$1<x$, $-1>x$, or $-\sqrt{3}<x<\sqrt{3}$” mean? There are three options, and you can pick any one of them? I’m going to edit this answer, but the edit won’t be public until it’s approved.

Comment: My suggested edit [was rejected](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32726/843797).